How to upload/share source files to StackExchange?
I wrote MS Word macros for word-to-latex and latex-to-word conversion. Is there standard scheme to share source files? Thank you in advance!

Thank you, Barbara! I have low reputation to post to meta.

@barbarabeeton https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723205/putting-equations-from-my-paper-in-latex-to-my-poster-made-using-microsoft-publi/723211#comment1799380_723211 ;).

I think generally the site isn't the best place to post source which you think other people might want to find and use, especially if it may get updated or altered later (but even if not). I'm not sure this would belong on CTAN. If not, maybe a code repository like GitHub?

@cfr Yes, I uploaded files to google disc. But nothing lasts forever.

@cfr Thank you! I thought about GitHub (I am not registered there). May be Mendeley Data (used to use) or so. CTAN is way too good for me.

I mention GitHub because there is already a wealth of TeX related stuff there. (Not just that, of course, but among other things.) if you look on CTAN, you can see where projects have their source code (if applicable - sometimes the source code just is the stuff on CTAN).

We may be able to move this even if you don't have enough rep to post there. Maybe @barbarabeeton knows? may as well try, I guess.

@cfr -- I haven't been involved in migrating questions, so I don't know how.  But I'll alert a moderator -- they're properly prepared for things.

@barbarabeeton If you vote to close, instead of closing, you can choose to migrate to meta. You have to click on the right close reason first and I always forget which it is, so even though I did it earlier, I can't now tell you which. (Maybe a site-specific reason? Or off-topic?)

File upload to TeX-sx is not possible: questions are intended to be self-contained and of reasonable length. If you wish to publish code for others to use, systems such as GitHub or CTAN are more suitable.
